# Cannot concatenate variables with R1C1 formula

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I'm currently having issues trying to get an R1C1 formula working while using variables.

```
Example = Range("O4").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Offset(5, 0).Address

Range(TableDaysStart).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & Example
```

The error application defined/object defined error comes up. Even though this is such a simple example of concatenation, it won't work. So what's gone wrong?

Funnily this would work

```
Range(TableDaysStart).Formula = "=" & Example
```

Anyone know why? I feel like it has to do with how I'm defining my variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are retrieving a cell address in xlA1 format (e.g. $D$2) but trying to use it as if it was in xlR1C1 format (e.g. R2C4).

You can ask for the address in xlR1C1 and use it as xlR1C1 in the .FormulaR1C1 like this,

```
dim example as string

Example = Range("O4").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Offset(5, 0).Address(referencestyle:=xlR1C1)
Range(TableDaysStart).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & Example
```

Or you can ask for the address in xlA1 style (the default) and use it as xlA1 in the .Formula like this.

```
dim example as string

Example = Range("O4").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Offset(5, 0).Address(referencestyle:=xlR1C1)
Range(TableDaysStart).Formula = "=" & Example
```

[Range.Address Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address)
[Range.Formula Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formula)
[Range.FormulaR1C1 Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formular1c1)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Probably to put more context, I actually wanted something like Range(TableDaysStart).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]" & Example. I needed R1C1 but also wanted to reference the A1 string style. I've changed my variable to R1C1 style with your help so it would all work. I was wondering though, is it actually not possible to mix R1C1 with some A1 in .FormulaR1C1?